# IE9 ignores font sometimes

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

My web application uses Arial as default font. But in a single place, the font family is ignored:

[image]

As you can see the labels on the left use Arial but in the popup DIV, it uses a serif font (probably New Roman Times, I'm not sure.)

I've styled the `td` directly and the content of the `td` is just an empty span plus the text.

When I toggle the checkboxes on the right, eventually IE9 will recalculate the styles and apply them properly.

Does anyone have any idea why IE ignores the CSS here?

Details: IE 9.0.29, Windows 7, ZK 6.5 as UI framework.

Comment: Does IE ignore other properties within that selector (e.g. `color: red;`)? Have you tried Arial with an uppercase A? Does it work for other fonts?

Comment: @grc: Please wait, trying ...

Comment: `background-color` works. All other styles are overwritten by stronger styles (as expected). When I use `!important`, then they work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've found these solutions but I don't know why they work when inheritance didn't:

```
.z-comboitem-text {
    font-family: Arial !important;
}
```

or

```
tr td.z-comboitem-text {
      font-family: Arial;
}
```

or using an inline style. If you use ZK 6, then use this code:

```
if( ZKUtils.isIE( 9 ) ) {
    item.setWidgetListener( "onBind", "jq(this).find('.z-comboitem-text').css('font-family', 'Arial')" );
}

public static boolean isIE( int version ) {
    Execution zkEnv = Executions.getCurrent();
    if( ! "ie".equals( zkEnv.getBrowser() ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    int actualVersion = zkEnv.getBrowser( "ie" ).intValue();
    return version == actualVersion;
}
```